# I want to understand why use reference function in this example?or The importance of reference in the function in c++?

Tags: c++

this code, I want to understand the need to use the reference in the prototype and what will happen if it is not used?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int& fun() 
{ 
    static int x = 10; 
    return x; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
    fun() ; 
    cout<<fun(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It might be more clear to you if it was written `int& fun()`. The reference is on the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a reference, you can access the variable from the "outside" world. If you "only" have the value, you can not change the variable anymore.

```
int& fun() 
{   
    static int x = 10; 
    return x;  
}
int main() 
{   
    std::cout<<fun() << std::endl;
    fun()=234;
    std::cout<<fun() << std::endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "reference function" here. The `&` is part of the return type and should better be written as

```
int& fun() {...
```

The function is returning a reference so that you can do

```
int main() 
{ 
    fun() = 6;
    cout<<fun();   // will print 6 
    return 0; 
}
```

If `fun` would return an `int` not a `int&` then the first line would not compile and each call to the function would return you the same value.

Note that in most cases returning a reference to a function local variable is wrong. The reason it is fine here is that `x` is `static`, meaning: it will be initialized exactly once and keeps its value across function calls.

For example this function will return a counter of how many times it got called:

```
int count_me() {
    static int x = 0;
    x+=1;
    return x;
}
```